# Facebook Conversion API: "System users can not have duplicate names. Use another name."

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-conversions-api

I'm trying to create access tokens for a few of my pixels, but I'm unable to do so due to the error message `"System users can not have duplicate names. Use another name."`.

This is the error I get in the pixel settings, when I click `Create access token`:

[image: Can't create access token]

`Failed to create access token. System users can not have duplicate names. Use another name.`

I don't know what this means in this context, or what I need to do to fix it and create my access tokens.

PS. Thread on [Facebook Developer Community Forum](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/5345608148862995/?post_id=5345608162196327); no responses at the time of posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way that this error was resolved was to be made a complete Business Manager admin on the account. Once that access level was granted to me, the error disappeared, and I was able to generate access tokens.